# Nexus integration with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, nexus

Is there a way to list all the version uploaded in Nexus repositories.
I am working with Jenkins, and trying to show the versions uploaded in Nexus repositories.

EDIT:

I am not using MAVEN releases, i have the compresses files as zip.
The format we have is ,

```
ABCD releases
 com.abc.abcd
   appname
    v1.0.0
      app_v1.0.0.zip
```

How do i use Repository connector /Artifact resolver to configure to list all the releases under ABCD releases.

Answer (score 0):

yes with jenkins nexus plugin you can make a parametrized job to display a specific version before the job start.
more detail look at this page

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Repository+Connector+Plugin

Comment: I have the compressed package in the format of zip file which is not a maven code in NEXUS. How can I configure in Repository Connector plugin to list the nexus packages list

Comment: @useranon have you found a solution?